# Javascript RegExp not working

Tags: javascript, regex

```
 "<circle cx='24' cy='24' fill='#CA3737' r='24'>".match(
            new RegExp("((?![0-9])(\w+)-*(\w*) *= *)(([0-9.]+)|('.+?')|(\w+))",'g')
     )
```

giving null while this expression is giving correct output on http://regexr.com/

i need a regular expression to find attributes of a tag.

Comment: This question is [off-topic (#1)](/help/on-topic). Please review [ask] and include a [mcve] along with a full description of the problem you're having.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use the regex by surrounding it with `/`.The problem is your code was that `new RegExp` results in a regex that is different from what you expect

**Your regex:**

```
/((?![0-9])(\w+)-*(\w*) *= *)(([0-9.]+)|('.+?')|(\w+))/g
```

**new RegExp() output**

```
/\/((?![0-9])(w+)-*(w*) *= *)(([0-9.]+)|('.+?')|(w+))/g
```

The below snippet gives the same result as `regexr.com`

```js
console.log("<circle cx='24' cy='24' fill='#CA3737' r='24'>".match(
           /((?![0-9])(\w+)-*(\w*) *= *)(([0-9.]+)|('.+?')|(\w+))/g
     )
            );
```

Comment: working fine ,thanx